# JQUERY AJAX Call of Server Side function, but hide function name

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I need to do a JQUERY Ajax call to few of my Server Side functions (ASP.NET). But I need to hide those function name from the call. So just like to address each function with some IDs as parameters to the AJAX URL. is that possible?

That means this is the normal way of call

```
      $.ajax(
        {
            type: "get",
            url: "ajax.aspx/Test",
            data: { name: 'ok' },
            success: function (result) { alert("successful!"); }
        })
```

But I need to do that this way

```
      $.ajax(
        {
            type: "get",
            url: "ajax.aspx?id=27&hash=23i292329dnshjsh239sdmk",
            data: { name: 'ok' },
            success: function (result) { alert("successful!"); }
        })
```

Hope the scenario is clear.. Let me know any more clarification required.

**Update**
So using that ID parameter server side code can call the corresponding function

Comment: Hide it from what? From showing in the browser url?

Comment: @MatúšDúbrava Sorry.. I just want to hide it from JS source

Comment: You will never be able to hide it from JS source. Simply because your browser needs that data to render a webpage locally. Therefore those files have to be stored locally.

Comment: @MatúšDúbrava Yes.. I know that I think.. But thats the reason I thought is there is any solution for that using that way I mentioned.. that means using parameters

Answer (score 0):

No, a user will always be able to figure out what calls you are making if you include it in Jquery.

You can compress and minify the javascript, but a person will always be able to find your url calls. Here's a js compression site, for example. http://jscompress.com/

However you can use the [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI).

Example:

```
var encoded = encodeURIComponent("your id will here");
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "get",
            url: "ajax.aspx/Test", //here add the encoded id if you want
            data: { name: 'ok' },
            success: function (result) { alert("successful!"); }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an flag parameter to the server,and on the server side, the constuct function will decide witch function to process by the flag.

Comment: But is that solution which I mentioned is possible? THat means using parameters to URL?

Comment: Yes,add to url is also ok.It is the same as pass an ajax parameter while using GET method.